# Negative sums of squares for Anova table of brglmFit object

Tags: r, glm

I am brglm2 to obtain bias reduced estimates of parameters in GLMs for seed germination proportions, because there are some treatments in which all of the replicates had the same proportion of successes.

When I use standard ML estimation, the parameter values and standard errors are highly inflated, and obtaining bias reduced estimates from brglm2 fixes this problem. However, when I use the 'Anova' function in the `car` package to obtain the Anova table, I get a negative Chi square likelihood ratio, and a p-value = 1.

For example, I'll make a similar dataset and show what has been done so far.

```
library(car)
library(brglm2)
Response = c(24, 19, 22, 24, 13, 16, 21, 20,  2,  7,  2,  3, 25, 24, 25, 25, 15, 15, 18, 14, 14, 16, 13, 13)
Trt1 = c("A",  "A",  "A",  "A",  "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C",  "C",  "C",  "A",  "A",  "A",  "A",  "C",  "C",  "C",  "C",  "B","B", "B", "B")
Trt2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B","B")
weights = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 14, 16, 21, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 14, 16, 13, 13)

df = data.frame(as.factor(Trt1),as.factor(Trt2),as.numeric(Response),as.numeric(weights))


options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

glm_ML = glm((Response/weights) ~ Trt1 * Trt2, data = df, weights=weights,family="binomial")
```

We can see that the estimates for the parameters and errors are very high, but the Anova table makes sense.

```
summary(glm_ML)

Call:
glm(formula = (Response/weights) ~ Trt1 * Trt2, family = "binomial", 
    data = df, weights = weights)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.83346  -0.37392   0.00012   0.71998   1.81866  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    5.171    604.771   0.009    0.993
Trt11         -1.828    604.771  -0.003    0.998
Trt12          7.662   1209.542   0.006    0.995
Trt21         -3.663    604.771  -0.006    0.995
Trt11:Trt21    2.411    604.771   0.004    0.997
Trt12:Trt21   -4.922   1209.542  -0.004    0.997

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 318.547  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  19.407  on 18  degrees of freedom
AIC: 71.33

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18

Anova(glm_ML,test="LR",type=3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: (Response/weights)
          LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Trt1       232.625  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
Trt2         8.181  1   0.004234 ** 
Trt1:Trt2    0.183  2   0.912453    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If we use `brglm2` to fit the model:

```
glm_brGLM = glm((Response/weights)~Trt1 * Trt2,data=df,family = "binomial",weight = weights,method="brglmFit")

summary(glm_brGLM) 

Call:
glm(formula = (Response/weights) ~ Trt1 * Trt2, family = "binomial", 
    data = df, weights = weights, method = "brglmFit")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7643  -0.4083   0.4876   0.8781   1.7621  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.2538     0.3184   7.078 1.47e-12 ***
Trt11         0.8695     0.4082   2.130 0.033156 *  
Trt12         2.0350     0.5745   3.542 0.000397 ***
Trt21        -0.8818     0.3184  -2.769 0.005623 ** 
Trt11:Trt21  -0.1896     0.4082  -0.465 0.642221    
Trt12:Trt21   0.4431     0.5745   0.771 0.440526    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 318.55  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  20.78  on 18  degrees of freedom
AIC: 72.703

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


Anova(glm_brGLM, test = "LR", type=3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: (Response/weights)
          LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Trt1       231.252  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
Trt2         6.808  1   0.009076 ** 
Trt1:Trt2   -1.190  2   1.000000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't receive any errors or warnings, but something seems incorrect about that last Anova table. Why is the LR Chisq term for the interaction negative, when it should always be positive? The same is true for an F-test (which is not appropriate for binomial distributed data), but not the Wald test, which is not as good of a test as the likelihood ratio test.

```
Anova(glm_brGLM, test = "F", type = 3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: (Response/weights)
Error estimate based on Pearson residuals 

           Sum Sq Df F values    Pr(>F)    
Trt1      231.252  2 107.2854 9.965e-11 ***
Trt2        6.808  1   6.3167    0.0217 *  
Trt1:Trt2  -1.190  2  -0.5520    1.0000    
Residuals  19.399 18                       

Anova(glm_brGLM, test = "Wald", type=3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: (Response/weights)
            Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)  1 50.0923  1.467e-12 ***
Trt1         2 90.3255  < 2.2e-16 ***
Trt2         1  7.6674   0.005623 ** 
Trt1:Trt2    2  0.6819   0.711081    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I wonder if it is some problem with how I am writing the code or if it is a problem with the `Anova` function in the `car` package? It could also be an artifact of bias correction, but then is it inappropriate to use in this case (which would make it a question to be moved to stats exchange)?

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is statistical rather than computational.  You may be stuck with inference based on Wald estimates/comparisons (which is often the case when you depart from strict likelihood to various forms of penalized/quasi-/pseudo-/etc. likelihood ...)

Comment: That was my worry, I really prefer to use a more robust test. The results are pretty similar when using the Wald test scores, but will see an interaction in another set of analyses which also have a separation problem become significant. Of course we could always add a caveat explaining why borderline significance could be suspect. Thanks for the guidance.